# Sum of a column in SharePoint 2010 Dataview webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How can I get a sum (total) of a column when using a dataview webpart?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this blog post by Marc D Anderson:
http://sympmarc.com/2011/07/19/summing-a-column-in-a-data-view-web-part-dvwp/

Quoting:

> The most common approach would be to emit a table row in the
>   dvt_1.body template (or equivalent) which uses the sum() function. An
>   example would be something like this. [... code sample]
>
> Of course, you can also ask SharePoint Designer to add the XSL for the total in the Common Dialogs under Sorting and Grouping, but as usual, the XSL will be a bit bloated and you won’t have as much control over the formatting.

So, either use the Sorting and Grouping options for the web part and suffer the code bloat of SPD, or hone your XSLT skills and add the sum with your own code, modeled after Marc's example.

Comment: thanks.
I ended up displaying total of all columns in the footer and then hiding the table. My DWP had to be filtered and I was after only one row